# where is a sample JAX-RS client sample?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, yahoo-api

I'm aware of the [Java API for Yahoo Finance](http://yahoofinance-api.com/).  I'm looking for a sample "hello world" client which uses, for example, Yahoo Finance, or, perhaps, some other publicly available RESTful API to test against.

see also:

https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:24:0::::P24_CONTENT_ID,P24_PREV_PAGE:8145,1

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html

The Jersey example above seems ok.  Just adapt it to Yahoo Finance?

(Not a well researched question, admittedly.  Only trying to avoid going down a rabbit hole.)

Comment: https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/jaxrs/jaxrs-client

Comment: What exactly about the Client API in the Jersey documentation do you not get, or can't figure out how to apply?

Answer (score 2):

That link you provided is a link to the Java library for the Yahoo API, and doesn't really show it "raw" REST API we can use from any client. So I'll redirect you to the a different API. Since we are on Stackoverflow, wouldn't it be fitting to use the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/).

If you scroll down to the bottom of the page, you will see APIs. Some are secured APIs, but that is a little more complicated discussion, and you will need to know a little about OAuth to get them to work. I'll leave that out of the discussion for now.

But without signing up for any account (or signing up a Stack app), we can make simple GET requests for things like answers, questions, and so on (normal things that wouldn't require authorization; simple read only)

If you look at the APIs, go to **Question** and you will see a link to

> [/questions/{ids}](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids)
>          Get the questions identified by a set of ids.

Click on it and you will see this at the bottom

[image]

Type `29336802` in the `id` field (which is the id of this question). You should see the URL change with the `{id}` replaced with the ID you input. Now how <kbd>Run</kbd>. You should see this JSON response

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "tags": [
                "web-services",
                "rest",
                "java-ee",
                "jax-rs",
                "yahoo-api"
            ],
            "owner": {
                "reputation": 1582,
                "user_id": 262852,
                "user_type": "registered",
                "accept_rate": 69,
                "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e4e17e45f2e8cc967a8695131910f365?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
                "display_name": "Thufir",
                "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/262852/thufir"
            },
            "is_answered": false,
            "view_count": 6,
            "answer_count": 0,
            "score": 0,
            "last_activity_date": 1427676465,
            "creation_date": 1427676465,
            "question_id": 29336802,
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29336802/where-is-a-sample-jax-rs-client-sample",
            "title": "where is a sample JAX-RS client sample?"
        }
    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "quota_max": 300,
    "quota_remaining": 267
}
```

Now we know the format of the JSON response, we can manipulate with our client side code.

For the example, I am using Maven, and adding these two dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Here's the code and then result. I'll explain the code afterwards

```
public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String url = "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/29336802";
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        client.register(GZipEncoder.class);
        WebTarget target = client.target(url);
        target = target.queryParam("order", "desc")
                .queryParam("sort", "activity")
                .queryParam("site", "stackoverflow");

        Response response = target.request()
                .accept("application/json; charset=utf-8")
                .acceptEncoding("gzip").get();

        String json = response.readEntity(String.class);
        response.close();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, 
                TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructMapType(
                        Map.class, String.class, Object.class));

        List<LinkedHashMap> items = (List<LinkedHashMap>)map.get("items");
        Map<String, Object> itemMap = items.get(0);

        Map<String, Object> userMap = (Map<String, Object>)itemMap.get("owner"); 
        Integer userId = (Integer)userMap.get("user_id");
        String displayName = (String)userMap.get("display_name");
        String profileImageUrl = (String)userMap.get("profile_image");

        Image image = ImageIO.read(new URL(profileImageUrl));
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        panel.add(new JLabel("User ID: " + userId));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Display Name: " + displayName), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);    
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Explanation:

Now there are plenty of Stack exchange Java clients already out there, but I am just demonstrating how this would be done on a lower level.

First we build the `Client` and specify the target

```
final String url = "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/29336802";
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(GZipEncoder.class);
WebTarget target = client.target(url);
target = target.queryParam("order", "desc")
        .queryParam("sort", "activity")
        .queryParam("site", "stackoverflow");
```

You can obtain the url by right clicking on the link in the above image, and (in Firefox) select [`Copy Link Location`] from the context menu. It will give you

> `http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/29336802?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow`

(Remember to type the id in again. The first request me made when we hit "run", wiped it out)

You can see the URL in my code is different. I actually just split up the query params, just to give a better idea of what we can do with Client API. We register the `GZipEncoder` as the response will be compressed.

Then we build the request and and send out the request with the final `get()` call.

```
Response response = target.request()
        .accept("application/json; charset=utf-8")
        .acceptEncoding("gzip").get();
```

We set a couple of headers with the request builder method `accept` and `acceptEncoding`, which will set the `Accept` and `Accept-Encoding` headers, respectively.

Then we deserialize the response body to a `String`

```
String json = response.readEntity(String.class);
response.close();
```

The next few lines, you have to have a little understanding of JSON and how Jackson's default mappings map JSON parts to Java Objects. It may be a little confusing, but because I didn't want to create POJOs for this example (as that is the most common way to work with Jacskon), I simply mapped the JSON parts to the default collections.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, 
        TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructMapType(
                Map.class, String.class, Object.class));

List<LinkedHashMap> items = (List<LinkedHashMap>)map.get("items");
Map<String, Object> itemMap = items.get(0);

Map<String, Object> userMap = (Map<String, Object>)itemMap.get("owner"); 
Integer userId = (Integer)userMap.get("user_id");
String displayName = (String)userMap.get("display_name");
String profileImageUrl = (String)userMap.get("profile_image");
```

Then I simple extracted some of the details from the JSON like the user id and display name. And also the url to your profile image, which I request with `ImageIO.read(URL)` to obtain the actual image. The rest of the code is simply some GUI related stuff to present the information I extracted

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(new URL(profileImageUrl));
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));

JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

panel.add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
panel.add(new JLabel("User ID: " + userId));
panel.add(new JLabel("Display Name: " + displayName), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
```

The Jersey Client API, which for the most part is standard JAX-RS APIs, are well documented in the [link you provided](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html). For further understanding of it, I suggest you thoroughly go through it.